# How can I filter testcases using custom meta-data in QAF?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, qaf

I am using [QAF](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/) for my automation project. I have project specific meta-data which has group SMOKE, regression, P1 and author with x,y,z name.

```
SCENARIO: SampleTest
META-DATA: {"description":"Sample Test Scenario","groups":["SMOKE"],"author":["x"]}

    #TODO: call test steps
END
```

I want to run only "smoke" group and author with "x" or "y". Is there any solution for these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example,

```
 public class TestSelenium {

    @Test(groups= "SMOKE")
    public void runSelenium() {
        System.out.println("runSelenium()");
    }

    @Test(groups= "Regression")
    public void runSelenium1() {
        System.out.println("runSelenium()1");
    }
}
```

Now if you want to execute only "SMOKE" group, do like this way.

```
<suite name="TestAll">
<!-- Run test method on group "selenium" only -->
<test name="selenium">

    <groups>
        <run>
            <include name="SMOKE" />
        </run>
    </groups>

     <classes>
        <class name="com.TestSelenium" />
     </classes>

   </test>

</suite>
```

For more details, inclusion/exclusion refer this.
http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#exclusions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `include` or `exclude` properties refer [documentation here](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/scenario_metadatata_filter_include_exclude_prop.html).
For example:

```
include= {'author': ['x']}
```

to run all scenario with author value x.
you can provide this properties in any property file or as system property or in run configuration xml file refer [different ways of providing prop](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/different_ways_of_providing_prop.html).